# How is hataras nedarim (annullment of vows) done one behalf of one's wife?

Tags: rosh-hashanah-new-year, marriage, women, nedarim-shevuot

I've heard:

- Just have her in mind
- State it outright "this is for my wife too"
- Today I saw someone do the whole thing in the plural -- "any vow that *we* vowed .. *we* hereby regret ..."

Any input on this, please?

Answer (score 2):

Anecdotally, today I heard someone do #2 on your list after inquiring about #3 and being told by the *beis din* of *hedyotos** not to.

*in the technical sense - no offense to them

Comment: Important note: bdoh.org is not yet registered, and Purim is only 6.5 months away.